# Sorting an STL Map from lowest to greatest value

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary

I have an STL map that has String keys and int values. I need to put the items into a new map with int keys and String values, such that the keys are sorted from lowest to greatest.

For example I have a map with these values(key, value):

```
"A", 5
"B", 2
"C", 8
"D", 4
```

I would like them to then be arranged in such a way that they look like this(key, value):

```
2, "B"
4, "D"
5, "A"
8, "C"
```

Where the value from the original map becomes the key, and the key becomes the value.

I know that I need to add the values from the original map to a new map, but I'm not sure how I would add them in a way that they're sorted from lowest to greatest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along these lines perhaps:

```
std::map<std::string, int> old_map = ...;  // initialized somehow
std::map<int, std::string> new_map;

std::transform(old_map.begin(), old_map.end(),
  std::inserter(new_map, new_map.end()),
  [](decltype(old_map)::iterator it) {
    return std::make_pair(it->second, it->first);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

For each pair in the original map, reverse the pair and insert into the other map. The sorting is automatic because [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is sorted by key.

Also, if you might have multiple keys in the original map with the same data (for example both `"A"` and `"E"` have the data `5`) then you need to be using [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) instead.

Comment: So std::map automatically sorts from lowest to greatest when the key is an int?

Comment: @Darren Yes, because the default sorting behaviour is `std::less<>`

Comment: Okay thank you, that will work fine then.

Answer (score 1):

For `std:map`, it is order by key default.

```
Internally, the elements in a map are always sorted by its key following a specific strict weak ordering criterion indicated by its internal comparison object (of type Compare).
```

Please read the link:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<string, int> myMap;
    myMap["D"] = 4;
    myMap["C"] = 8;
    myMap["B"] = 2;
    myMap["A"] = 5;
    cout<<"before:"<<endl;
    for_each(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), [](auto& element){cout<<element.first<<" "<<element.second<<endl;});

    map<int, string> otherMap;
    cout<<"after:"<<endl;
    for_each(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), [&otherMap](auto& element){otherMap[element.second] = element.first;});
    for_each(otherMap.begin(), otherMap.end(), [](auto& element){cout<<element.first<<" "<<element.second<<endl;});
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code exmaple:
the output is:

```
before:
A 5
B 2
C 8
D 4
after:
2 B
4 D
5 A
8 C
```

So you don't sort it by yourself.